# Runeforging won't open for new Death Knight

Tags: azerothcore

I have a running server within Docker and when I create a new Death Knight, the second quest to open Runeforging and apply a buff to the provided weapon will not function. Runeforging appears in the spellbook, but does not open an additional window when clicked on so the quest cannot be completing and using the GM command to complete the quest will not complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting here what I said on Discord for reference. Runeforging was an issue in the core. This isn't related to your setup. Here is the related issue, fixed and already merged in last AC version: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/6612